# Zoho Deluge : How to send an Email

Tags: zoho

I am trying to send an email by using Zoho Custom Function.

**My Code** :

```
sendmail
    [
        from: "email@gmail.com"
        to: "email@gmail.com"
        subject: "Test Email"
        message: "This is mail Body"
    ]
```

**Give this error :**

In cases where From: address is not a zoho.adminuserid or zoho.loginuserid, the To: address can only be zoho.adminuserid and the sendmail task cannot have any CC: or BCC: address.

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing this code for Zoho Creator, It only allows the From Email Address to be zoho.adminuserid (Admin Email) or zoho.loginuserid (Logged-in User Email) system variables.

You can allow more "From" addresses by adding them as Verified Emails. Please refer to https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/forms/set-email-notifications.html#verified%20email%20address.

In the case you provided, you should consider adding "email@gmail.com" as a verified email address.

Answer (score 2):

**Try This:**

```
sendmail
[
    from: zoho.adminuserid
    to: "email@gmail.com"
    subject: "Test Email"
    message: "This is mail Body"
]
```

**Note:** 
You can not use both custom email address. One Should zoho system variable or both should be zoho system variable.