# Forward SMS from Twilio to Email using Zoho Deluge

Tags: email, sms, twilio, zoho

As far as I know, you can't forward SMS messages to an email address with just a TwiML Bin. Therefore, I would like to forward Twilio SMS messages to my Zoho email address using Zoho [Deluge](https://www.zoho.com/creator/deluge.html) (instead of the other alternatives I've seen: [Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44790973) or [SendGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52481378)).

I intend to use the free Zoho Deluge plan. I have never used Deluge before. This question is intended to help me discover whether Deluge can be a replacement for Google Apps Script for simple functionality like this where a form is not needed.

The basic way to send an email using Deluge is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52512046).

I hope Deluge can do the same thing Google Apps Script can do.

Comment: Here is an example of doing just send with Twilio Functions/Sendgrid. Forward incoming SMS messages to email with Node.js, SendGrid and Twilio Functions - https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/07/forward-incoming-sms-messages-to-email-with-node-js-sendgrid-and-twilio-functions.html. You're correct, can't do this with just a TwiML Bin.

Comment: @Alan In this question, I'm looking for an example using Zoho Deluge. I have a separate question about using SendGrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To forward an SMS that is sent to your Twilio number you need to be able to receive an incoming HTTP request.

Zoho Deluge appears to allow you to [create functions that can be invoked](https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/script/functions.html). However, [the methods by which you can invoke a Deluge function](https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/script/invoking-a-function.html) do not include via an incoming HTTP request.

I'm not familiar with Deluge, but after a bit of navigating around the documentation I don't believe you can set up a URL that will invoke a function, therefore you can't use Deluge to forward incoming SMS messages with Twilio. As Alan suggests in the comments, you could use Twilio Functions to achieve this without reaching out to another service.